# Copy a base sheet multiple times based on a list located in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a copy of a tab named `Base` for every value contained in a single array on a tab called `List`.

Each copy of the `Base` tab needs to be named each value contained on the `List` tab. Cell `C1` on `Base` needs to be set to the value from the array `List` (which will also be the name of the tab).

The list will contain 300ish values, and having each tab in workbook as a copy of the original will oddly be the best solution for what will be a shared workbook.

I would like to flatten each worksheet to static values. Each worksheet with have a number of formulas that will cause performance issues if I leave as dynamic content.

Here is my code.

```
Sub Generator()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim b As String
    Dim e As String
    Dim s As Integer
    Sheets("List").Select
    b = "A1"
    e = Range(b).End(xlDown).Address

    For Each cell In Range(b, e)
        s = Sheets.Count
        Sheets("Base").Copy After:=Sheets(s)
        Range("C1").Select

        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = cell.Value

        Sheets(s + 1).Name = cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

After trying the solution, the only change is that I would like to re-calc the whole sheet (the functional equivalent of pushing the F9 key) after the new sheet is pasted but right before the sheet is flattened. I assume a line of code needs to be inserted as indicated below in the LetUsContinue sub.

```
    LetUsContinue:
          On Error GoTo 0 '--Turn off error handling.
           .Range("C1") = Cell.Value '--Change C1 to the name of current sheet.

  '---->>>>>recalc the sheet here

         .Cells.Copy '--Change all cells...
        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '--... to values.
    End With
Next Cell
```

Comment: So after a little more research, I've got it to work MOL how it needs to. One thing I would like to have a check for are if a list value was listed twice - it would throw an error and I've got nothing for it.

Comment: Just add `.Calculate` before `.Cells.Copy`. Take note of the full stop. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub MoreAndMoreSheets()

    Dim ListSh As Worksheet, BaseSh As Worksheet
    Dim NewSh As Worksheet
    Dim ListOfNames As Range, LRow As Long, Cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ListSh = .Sheets("List") '--Qualify our sheets.
        Set BaseSh = .Sheets("Base")
    End With

    LRow = ListSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '--Get last row of list.
    Set ListOfNames = ListSh.Range("A1:A" & LRow) '--Qualify our list.

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False '--Turn off flicker.
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual '--Turn off calculations.
    End With

    For Each Cell In ListOfNames '--For every name in list...
        BaseSh.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) '--Copy Base sheet.
        Set NewSh = ActiveSheet '--Let's name it NewSh.
        With NewSh
            On Error GoTo Boom '--In case of errors.
            .Name = Cell.Value '--Set the sheet's name to that of our current name in list.
            GoTo LetUsContinue '--Skip to the LetUsContinue block.
Boom: '--In case of duplicate names...
            .Name = "Dup" & Cell.Value '--Add "Dup" to beginning.
            .Tab.ColorIndex = 53 '--Change the tab color of the duplicate tab to orange for easy ID.
LetUsContinue:
            On Error GoTo 0 '--Turn off error handling.
            .Range("C1") = Cell.Value '--Change C1 to the name of current sheet.
            .Calculate '--Calculate page.
            .Cells.Copy '--Change all cells...
            .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '--... to values.
        End With
    Next Cell

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True '--Return to proper state.
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic '--Return to automatic calculation.
    End With

    BaseSh.Activate '--Select Base.
    MsgBox "Done!" '--Done!

End Sub
```

**Screenshots:**

***Set-up:***

[image]

***Result after running code:***

[image]

Read the comments. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I will mark the answer, but wanted to ask if there was a simple line of code to flatten the sheet AFTER copying. ANy thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for accepting. The last two lines in the inner loop (`.Cells.Copy` --> `.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`) converts the sheets into values (*flatten*) them, don't they? Or are they not working for you?